# Generate reducers dynamically (universal reducer for api calls)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

In redux how can i make reducers dynamically based on api call passed as string to an action-creator to reduce the boilerplate (so for each api call there was a dedicated key inside the store)?
And should i even try to do that?

Example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tp71Los/1/)

The problem is here:

```
export function universalFetchReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCHING_DATA' + action.metadata:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case 'FETCHING_DATA_SUCCESS' + action.metadata:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        data: action.data,
        dataFetched: true
      };
    case 'FETCHING_DATA_FAILURE' + action.metadata:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

For now i can create actions and their names based on url passed to an action-creator, but cannot make a dedicated reducer.

Comment: You want one reducer for all of your actions that request data from an api?

Comment: @Galupuf yes, but not exactly, i want to create a dedicated reducer for every singe api call (name of an action and a reducer function/store-object is based on a call name/metadata) and register it to the store. if thats the common thing, in a form of some lib, npm package, etc. I thought that creating an action/action-creator/reducer for every api call is a little redundant since its just a unique call every time. I have only found solution for a dynamic store code splitting but this is a different case. if this is a bad practice then i will just move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using `redux-injector`, followed its api to create an action creators and a simple async action creator (axios used):

```
export function getData(api) {
  return {
    type: `FETCHING_DATA_${api}`,
    meta: api
  }
}

export function universalFetchData(api) { 
  injectReducer(`universalFetch${api}`, universalFetchReducer);
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getData(api)) //Some initial action. Pass api to name actions
    axios
      .get(api)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(getDataSuccess(response.data, api)) //Some success action
      })
      .catch(error => getDataFailure(error.response.status, api))   } } //Some failure action
```

Then just fired an universalFetchData('path_to_api') from component and got `FETCHING_DATA_path_to_api` action in redux-devtools.

Got data from store 
`state.universalFetchReducer_path_to_api`
and passed this state to render with e.g. ramda's `pathOr` to set unkown initial state.

Lesson learned: you will be able to make many simple lazy loading api calls fast, but do this only if you know what data you're getting. For more dangerous logic use regular reducers upfront. This solution nowhere near acceptable but it gets job done.